# Cube going through thin part of mesh in rigid body simulation

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I'm trying to drop two "ice cubes" into a cup, so I set everything to rigid body and let gravity do the rest. However, the cubes are going through part (the thin part) of the mesh, yet colliding with the other.

Any ideas? Here's the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q_WcR0NOFCsiROlrthCJmV4OzThljEBQ/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing Source type to Base in the cup fixes the issue

Comment: So the cubes kept going through for me when I changed it to be so I ended up just reducing the height from which they fell and using base and that seemed to fix it